# I am trying to host discord.py bot on heroku and this error occurs

Tags: python, git, heroku, discord.py

This is full cmd :

```
C:\Users\twori\Desktop\development\python\discord.py>git push heroku master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.11
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r /tmp/build_a16c861c/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to /tmp/pip-req-build-622q7g33
remote:          Running command git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py /tmp/pip-req-build-622q7g33
remote:          WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
remote:          Running command git checkout -q rewrite
remote:          error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to discord-gut.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/discord-gut.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/discord-gut.git'
```

Honestly I don't know anything about GIT, but I just searched about this error and tried everything.
Please tell me what's wrong with this.
+) I Found this: https://help.heroku.com/O0EXQZTA/how-do-i-switch-branches-from-master-to-main
and I tried, but I get the same result:

```
C:\Users\twori\Desktop\development\python\discord.py>git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 683 bytes | 227.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.11
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r /tmp/build_0ed9bf17/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to /tmp/pip-req-build-bii5i34v
remote:          Running command git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py /tmp/pip-req-build-bii5i34v
remote:          WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
remote:          Running command git checkout -q rewrite
remote:          error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git.
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to discord-gut.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/discord-gut.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/discord-gut.git'
```

Comment: Your issue is this `Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite`. Edit your `requirements.txt` and change the line containing `discord.py` to just `discord.py` or `discord.py==1.3.4`. The rewrite git branch no longer exists and is now the main branch.

Comment: I revised requirements.txt :
`discord.py==1.3.4 
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite 
PyNaCl==1.3.0 
pandas 
dnspython==1.16.0 
async-timeout==3.0.1`
and It gives me the same error.

Comment: delete `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite`

Comment: @TinNguyen : you should probably re-post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r /tmp/build_a16c861c/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to /tmp/pip-req-build-622q7g33
remote:          Running command git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py /tmp/pip-req-build-622q7g33
remote:          WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
remote:          Running command git checkout -q rewrite
remote:          error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

It tried to find the rewrite branch but it couldn't find it. The rewrite git branch no longer exists and is now the main branch.

In your `requirements.txt` you have the following line:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
```

Change that to `discord.py` or `discord.py==1.3.4`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I successfully uploaded it into heroku. Thanks!